# WinUI 3 COMException Error when updating TextBlock Text in a timer function

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3

I'm trying to update the Text of a `TextBlock` every time a timer fires. Here is my code:

```
public static DateTime startTime;
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Elapsed += Timer_Tick;
timer.Start();

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

When I run it I get `Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in WinRT.Runtime.dll`. All other code I put in that function will run, it just won't update the text of my TextBlock.
I've also tried with a `System.Threading.Timer` and get the same error.

How can I fix this to update the Text of my TextBlock every time a second elapses? Every answer I find doesn't seem to work with WinUI 3.

Comment: Try `DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() => { timerLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); } );` in `Timer_Tick` instead

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, that worked! Thank you! I had tried `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>` but that doesn't seem to work anymore with WinUI 3. Your code solved it. If you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A timer from `System.Timers` will tick on a non-UI thread, so you must use a [Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.dispatching.dispatcherqueue) somehow.

You can use the one on the current [Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.dispatcherqueue) or get one from the current thread (if it has a dispatcher queue) using the [DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.dispatching.dispatcherqueue.getforcurrentthread).

Then your code can be written like this:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) => DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
{
    timerLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
});
```

Note that you can also use a timer provided by the DispatcherQueue itself with the [DispatcherQueue.CreateTimer Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.dispatching.dispatcherqueue.createtimer) which will automatically tick in the proper thread.